# I can not find /usr/share/php5/php.ini-development file

Tags: 12.04, php

I install LAMP according [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Set_mysql_bind_address). But I cannot find /usr/share/php5/php.ini-development file . My php is PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 . Apache is Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) . I use ubuntu 12.04 amd64. How to know which is used development or production.
Thanks

```
$ ls /usr/share/php5/php.ini* -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68428 Mar 11 22:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68105 Mar 11 22:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.cli
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68107 Mar 11 22:44 /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production-dist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development`

If this command returns nothing, then your PHP uses dev configuration.

`diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production`

If this command returns nothing your PHP uses production configuration.

If you want to use dev configuration,

`sudo cp /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

If you want to use production configuration,

`sudo cp /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: Great answer. One could add the flag s to the last two commands to create a Symbolic link (instead of copying the file). For example: sudo cp -s /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. For more information, visit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link and http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_cp.htm

Comment: Another comment: Before you do all this, you can backup your phpinfo file in this way: sudo mv /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.bak

Comment: Right and then create a symlink to dev to php.ini

Comment: Just for reference, if you are running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, you can find the example ini files in: > /usr/share/php5/php.ini-development >
> /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt-file` I get the following:

```
$ apt-file search php.ini-development
php5-common: /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development
```

So check if you have that package installed (if you have PHP installed you should) and check if that file is what you are looking for.

Comment: I find /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development too. But I am not sure how to convert production to development now.

Comment: PHP configuration is stored in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, so you need to replace that file with the configuration you want and then restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact syntax to be typed as below:

First backup your original "php.ini" file using the command in terminal window as below:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.bak
```

then copy development version of php.ini to the original php.in by the below command:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

then now check if the development version of php.ini is running by the below command:

```
 $ diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development
```

If no response comes then the development version of php.ini settings are current and running else the production version is still running. That's it !!

Comment: This doesn't work because `/usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development` doesn't ship with the current PHP packages.